# jquery & doc.createElement throws error for <

Tags: javascript, jquery

Both the `$("<test")` & `document.createElement(",test")` throws error due to < character associated to the text. I do not want to replace the character & wanted to see if there is option to create dom or jquery object using such text. I know replace will work but since the code is pre-existing & also since code is written such that it assume it can either have the simple text (textnode) or html tag (like span) hence this error is occuring as it fails to check if it is proper self closing html tag.

I am thinking of creating it to xml node & then check if the childnode is textNode or not before trying to create jquery object,however I am looking for suggestion & best approach to tackle such issue. I know replace of < will work & also there is no need to check for attributes of plain text but since the code is dynamic it sometimes retrieves plain text & some time it gives valid html tag that why this issue appears

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? you can always test for the first character. you could also execute your calls in a `try` block, acting accordingly inside the exception handler.

Comment: Even with a simple text node, what you are trying to do seems really wrong.

Comment: Can you give an example on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what your exact end goal is, but basically you need to do something like this:

```
function makeElemHack( str ) {
    var div = $("<div>").html(str);  //create a div and add the html
    var html = div.html();           //read the html
    if (!html.length) {              //if the html has no length the str was invalid
        div.html(str.replace(/</g,"&lt;"));   //escape the &lt; like text should be
        //div.text(str);   //or you can just add it as plain text
    }
    return div;               //with the div wraper
    //return div.contents();  //without the div wrapper
}

var bd = $("body");

bd.append( makeElemHack("<p>Hello</p>") );
bd.append( makeElemHack("1<0") );
bd.append( makeElemHack("<booo") );
```

Comment: Please refer to my solution on below fiddle it uses xml & nodeType function to see if the node is textnode or html. tag.http://jsfiddle.net/QxdYm/2/ (works in Firefox only)

Comment: Why should I refer to your solution? And what about `testTxtNode("<test"); which you talk about in your ORIGINAL post?`

Comment: @user593029 your example doesn't seem to work as you are asking ... `testTxtNode("<test")` thinks it is an HTML node

Comment: sorry for the confusion since error was occruing for both '<' & '&lt;'